# Почему не работают media-queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

```
 body, html {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;

 }
 #header {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
     max-width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: blue;
 }
 #container {
     max-width: 100%;
     height: 700px;
     background-color: red;
 }
 .block1 {
     margin: 25px 0 0 100px;
     width: 700px;
     height: 25px;
     background-color: yellow;
 }


@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    .block1 {
        margin-left: 25px;
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="block1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Не срабатывает media-query для block1. В чем проблема? Как это решить?

Comment: 375 чего?) (пс: добавьте `px`)

Comment: @meine исправил. Все равно не работает

Answer (score 0):

Все работает  - запустите здесь и поизменяйте размер

```css
body, html {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;

 }
 #header {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
     max-width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: blue;
 }
 #container {
     max-width: 100%;
     height: 700px;
     background-color: red;
 }
 .block1 {
     margin: 25px 0 0 100px;
     width: 700px;
     height: 25px;
     background-color: yellow;
 }


@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    .block1 {
        margin-left: 25px;
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="block1">12345</div>
        </div>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Перед:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я изменил ширину окна меньше чем на 375px, но block1 не стал по ширине равным 200px и margin-left  не уменьшился до 25px

Comment: У меня не работает :(

Comment: Может быть надо что-то установить для того, чтобы media queries работали? Я не понимаю. На двух устройствах запускаю не работает.

Comment: Запустил на десктопе в Firefox, Crome, Opera и IE11 - все работает. Смотрите, что у Вас с компом/браузером.

Comment: В Edge тоже работает. Может, кэш почистить тщательно.

Comment: Я понял в чем проблема. Хром не дает сжать окно на 375px и меньше. В edge и IE все работает, т.к. окно может сжаться на такие размеры

Comment: Я попробовал изменить max-width на max-width: 500px и в хроме заработало

Comment: Теперь все работает

Comment: В хроме, при таких моментах, нажимаете F12 и Ctrl+Shit+M - и смотрите в разных мобильных разрешениях.